# AWS lambda sdk error: "TooManyRequestsException"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am building an service that sending scraped data with emails to subscribers.

The architecture of service is simple:

1. "Lambda A" fetches target URLs. **(The total amounts of URLs is only 14)**
2. "Lambda A" triggers "Lambda B" that actually scrapes data with AWS-SDK.
3. "Lambda A" waits for executions of every "Lambda B" to save whole scraped data in AWS S3.
4. When the object is saved in specific S3, "Lambda C" is triggered and it starts to send emails to subscribers.

However, the problem occurs in step 2. Here is my "Lambda A" code.

```js
const databaseUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-lambda');

const client = new LambdaClient();

// Connect to DB and get URLs.
const connect = async (url) => {
  try {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(url);
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.query("select * from source");
    const result = rows.map((source) => {
      return {
        name: source.name,
        url: source.url,
        description: source.description,
      };
    });
    connection.end();
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    return "err";
  }
};

/**
 * This function invokesa lambda function synchronously to perform subsequent logic(Trigger Send Email)
 */
const invoke = async (client, source) => {
  const params = {
    FunctionName: 'scraper',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(source)
  };
  return await client.send(new InvokeCommand(params));
};

const handler = async (event) => {
  const sources = await connect(databaseUrl);
  
  const lambdas = sources.map((source) => invoke(client, source));
  
  const results = await Promise.all(lambdas);
  
  const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
  
  for (const result of results) {
    const payload = result.Payload;
    console.log(decoder.decode(payload));
  }
  
  return JSON.stringify(results);
};

module.exports = {
  handler
}
```

And this is error trace from aws lambda.

```
{
    "errorType": "TooManyRequestsException",
    "errorMessage": "Rate Exceeded.",
    "name": "TooManyRequestsException",
    "$fault": "client",
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 429,
        "requestId": "d9a2b812-2c76-4cda-b688-201824c4194b",
        "attempts": 3,
        "totalRetryDelay": 762
    },
    "Type": "User",
    "Reason": "ConcurrentInvocationLimitExceeded",
    "stack": [
        "TooManyRequestsException: Rate Exceeded.",
        "    at de_TooManyRequestsExceptionRes (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lambda/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restJson1.js:5568:23)",
        "    at de_InvokeCommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lambda/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restJson1.js:3344:25)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:30:20",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26",
        "    at async invoke (/var/task/index.js:31:10)",
        "    at async Promise.all (index 8)",
        "    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/index.js:51:19)"
    ]
}
```

I found about "ConcurrentInvocationLimitExceeded" error from this document - [Invoke - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/api/API_Invoke.html). And additional info about lambda scaling from this document - [Lambda function scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html).

The document says that the reason such an error occurs is because no more than 1000 or so lambdas can be executed simultaneously. However my "Lambda A" calls only 14 additional lambda function. Is there any solution for my problem(architecture or code)?

Comment: I'd recommand to use a stepFunctions for what you want to build. It doesn't make sense to pay for a lambda that just waits for another one finish...

Comment: I will check that service. Thanks for saving my money :D

Comment: For Step 2, you could instead have Lambda A send messages to an Amazon SQS queue, which can triggers Lambda B. This way, Lambda will automatically scale and you can send more messages than available concurrency. However, the hard part is Step 3 -- knowing when all the workers have finished. It is always a shame to have a Lambda function waiting around for something else (and being billed). I agree with @brushtakopo that Step Functions is the 'proper' way to handle this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) page:

> New AWS accounts have reduced concurrency and memory quotas. AWS raises these quotas automatically based on your usage.

Check your actual quota in the AWS Lambda console dashboard. It is not uncommon for the initial quota to actually be 10, which will rise over time.